# Having trouble with pulling an API key from riot

Tags: json, api, laravel-5, api-key

Hi I am have a problem with pulling my Riot Api on laravel 5.6. This is a personal project and I don't know someone else that understands Laravel.
I am refistered on Riot to pull the API key.

I am getting this error:

```
file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or 
service not known (View: 
/home/allyvoxc/ksgg.allyvox.co.za/resources/views/pages/LOL.blade.php)
```

The line highlighted is

```
$summoner = json_decode($result)->$summonerName;
```

This is my code, I have removed my API code in the code down below.

```
@extends('header')

@section('content')
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Summoner Spy</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Summoner Spy</h1>
<?php
$apiKey = 'This is my API code';
$summonerName = 'lolnexus';

// get the basic summoner info
$result = 
file_get_contents('https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' 
. $summonerName . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
$summoner = json_decode($result)->$summonerName;
// var_dump($summoner);
?>
<h3>
<image height="64" width="64" src="http://avatar.leagueoflegends.com/na/<? 
php print $summonerName; ?>.png" valign="middle"/>
<?php print $summonerName ?>
</h3>
<div>
Level: <?php print $summoner->summonerLevel; ?>
</div>

<?php
// get that summoner's wins and losses for each game type
$result = 
file_get_contents('https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/stats/by- 
summoner/' . $summoner->id . '/summary?api_key=' . $apiKey);
$stats = json_decode($result);
// var_dump($stats);
foreach($stats->playerStatSummaries as $statSummary){
// $statSummary->losses: sometimes losses isn't set
$losses = property_exists($statSummary, 'losses')? $statSummary->losses : 
'(not available)';
print '<p><b>' . $statSummary->playerStatSummaryType . '</b>: ' .
    $statSummary->wins . ' wins, ' . $losses . ' losses</p>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for anyone that will be able to assist

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `GuzzleHttp` package: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

An example in your case would be:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/' . $summoner->id . '/summary', [
    'query' => [ 'api_key' => $apiKey ]
]);

if($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
    $json = json_decode($res->getBody());
    $summoner = $json->$summonerName
}
```

Additionally, I am not sure if this is going to be your final code. But the way you have set out your code kind of defeats the purpose of an MVC framework like Laravel.

You should gather all of your data in the `Controller` and then, in turn, pass that data to the `View`

I recommend this course for starting off with Laravel: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

And specifically Episode 5 for your current case: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/5

Comment: No its not the final code, I am going to use the controllers, starting up with a basic method so I can work from that point and know what I can use in the controller